# ActiveSupport::Configurable config object won't fully clone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I'm having some trouble understanding how to clone/duplicate a config object that uses ActiveSupport::Configurable.  I'm using the ActiveSupport::Configurable module to create a simple configuration object.  In some automated tests, I want to set aside the current configuration, and create a new config object with different value.  I have a method called `remember_config` which just does

```rb
module App
  class Config
    include ActiveSupport::Configurable

    def self.remember_config
      @previous_config = @config
      @config = @config.clone
    end
  end
end
```

The trouble occurs when I use it.

```rb
App.config.foo = 1 
App.config.foo # Returns 1
App.previous_config # Returns nil
App.remember_config
App.config.foo # Still returns 1
App.previous_config.foo # eturns 1
App.config.foo = 2
App.config.foo # Returns 2
App.config.previous_config.foo # Also returns 2, but I'd like it to return 1!
```

Why does the last line return 2 instead of 1?  The `@previous_config` and `config` objects have different object_ids.  Maybe it's not a clone problem.  Maybe it's an issue with the way the ActiveSupport::Configurable magic works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using dup function rather then the clone function.

```
module App
  class Config
    include ActiveSupport::Configurable

    def self.remember_config
      @previous_config = @config
      @config = @config.dup
    end
  end
end
```

But you can not use class as singleton class.

Comment: I tried dup and it didn't work either.  It also looks like a deep_dup method is available and that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you send me the calling parameters for the above configurations? If nothing works we can always write these on to file or database :D

Comment: I ended up dropping `ActiveSupport::Configurable` and used regular instance variables instead.  `ActiveSupport::Configurable` seems to have some issues with cloning.